# Windows 10 WDK Computer Provisioning Error

Tags: windows, driver, provisioning, wdk

I'm fairly new to Driver development but I'm currently using the latest version of Visual Studio and Windows 10 on both my Host and Target computer. I'm trying to set up provisioning for my target computer so that I can test the drivers that I make! However, I'm having an issue... I get this error every time I try to add my target computer to set up provisioning (Driver -> Test -> Configure Devices -> Add New Device). My computer hostname is correct (I can do 'ping PCNAME' and it works just fine). Visual studio, WDK, and the Windows 10 SDK are run on both computers. I've completely gone through Microsofts guide on how to provision a computer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1) and done everything it says. I've turned off the firewall completely. Every time I try to set up the provisioning though I get this error

```
  Name: Install Driver Test Components
  Path: C:\Users\Ztowne13\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\WDKTestInfrastructure\InfrastructureTaskGroups\Install Driver Test Components.xml
  Target Computer: New Computer
Install Driver Test Components: Host Computer: DESKTOP-5S0AEBO
Install Driver Test Components: Host Architecture: x86
Install Driver Test Components: Host 64bit Operating System: True
Install Driver Test Components: Host Operating System Version: 10.0.17134.0
Install Driver Test Components: Process Administrator Privilege: False
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 15, Message: ""
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 15, Message: "Copying required files"
[19:24:24:121]: Copying required files
[19:24:24:539]: Task "Copying required files" was aborted because an unexpected error occured during execution.

None of the discovered or specified addresses match the socket address family.
Parameter name: context
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 15, Message: "    Task "Copying required files" was aborted because an unexpected error occured during execution.

None of the discovered or specified addresses match the socket address family.
Parameter name: context"
Task result status updated: Aborted
Result completed
Test process exit code: 0
[19:24:24:543]: None of the discovered or specified addresses match the socket address family.
Parameter name: context
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 15, Message: "None of the discovered or specified addresses match the socket address family.
Parameter name: context"
Progress event: Current: 1, Max: 15, Message: "Computer configuration log file://C:/Users/Ztowne13/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/WDKTestInfrastructure/ProvisioningLogs/Driver%20Test%20Computer%20Configuration%2020181129192424070.log"
```

and this file is the configuration log suggested at the very end if you were curious.

I have no idea why this is not working and I can't provision my computer, any help would be much appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: It is a pretty obscure networking issue.  Obscure is good, narrows down the Google hits when you query the error message.  The one from quest.com looks most useful to me.  Get IT staff involved if you can't sort it out yourself, you probably need them anyway to fix the underlying cause.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you link me to that quest.com page you found? I've done a lot of googling and have been unsuccessful in finding anything relevant or useful :/

Comment: https://support.quest.com/appassure/kb/120972/backup-transfers-fail-intermittently-with-error-system-argumentexception-none-of-the-discovered-or-specified-addresses-match-the-socket-address-family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... I solved it. All I did is type ipconfig in my target computer and put the IP (10.0.0.X) in the "Network Host Name" category instaed of the computer's name (DESKTOP-TESTPC) despite Microsoft's article saying to put the PC name and not the local IP.